# Get LoadbalancerName from imported ALB using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Similar question not answered here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/discussions/15975

I'm trying to get ALB Name for a metric but the Interface does not have the `loadBalancerName`

I know that I can get the Name from the ARN, but was hoping to not have to parse the ARN for that.
Any alternative?

Ex

```
const existingLb = albv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer.fromLookup(this, `alb`, {
            loadBalancerArn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:REGION:ACC_ID:loadbalancer/app/THE_NAME_OF_THE_ALB/blablabla,
        });

// Property 'loadBalancerName' does not exist on type 'IApplicationLoadBalancer'
new aws_cloudwatch.Metric({namespace: "AWS/ApplicationELB", metricName: "HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count", dimensionsMap: { LoadBalancerName: existingLb.loadBalancerName} })

// the "workaround"

new aws_cloudwatch.Metric({namespace: "AWS/ApplicationELB", metricName: "HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count", dimensionsMap: { LoadBalancerName: existingLb.loadBalancerArn.split('/').reverse()[1]} })
```

Comment: Parsing seems your best bet, unless the imported `existingLb` construct is only used to set ALB string name in the metric.  In that case you don't need `existingLb` - just hardcode the ALB name.

Comment: Do you have another stack that is creating the `existingLb`? If so, then you can simply use  SSM parameter to store an ALB name, as described in the link you posted in your question.

Comment: No, unfortunatelly the LB I have is just an hardcoded ARN, I can indeed just parse the ARN directly, put it there hoping to have some parser built in :D.
Will also update the answer later, as **for the metrics we need the FullName not only the LB name, in this case app/name/blabla**